# updating page layouts not reflecting the changes to the existing pages

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have updated the page layout for SharePoint online, but the changes are not getting reflected to the existing pages. is this the expected behavior? or what is the procedure to update the layout so that all the existing pages also reflect with that changes. Please suggest.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Checking in/Publishing/approving the file should do the trick. You can do this in the master page gallery or via Sharepoint Designer (right click).

Answer (score 0):

Faced same issue in SP2013 (on premises). Added new Field to Page Layout, but it doesn't appear in the page. So what I did? Change the field name value from Internal Name to Display Name, and the field appears in the layout.

From:

```
<PublishingWebControls:RichImageField FieldName="ThumbnailImageInternal" AllowHyperLinks="false" DefaultAssetImageLocation="<% $SPUrl:~site/PublishingImages/ %>" runat="server"/><br />
```

To:

```
<PublishingWebControls:RichImageField FieldName="Thumbnail Image" AllowHyperLinks="false" DefaultAssetImageLocation="<% $SPUrl:~site/PublishingImages/ %>" runat="server"/><br />
```